# Disabling wp_tag_cloud() outputting inline CSS

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a way to disable Wordpress wp_tag_cloud() from outputting inline CSS?

Comment: This is probably better on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked there were no convenient way to do that. The bundled tag widget is quite simple, so many use more extensive plugins like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-tags/

I am not sure if that particular plugin will help you get rid of the inline CSS, but worth checking out!

Comment: Not a big fan of plugins. Luckily i came across this. http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Look at the [`wp_tag_cloud()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud) docs and check out the `format` arg. Both the `flat` and `array` format types look like they will serve your purpose. This arg is actually passed through to `wp_generate_tag_cloud()` (in `wp-includes/category-template.php`, line 613) if you want to take a look at what it's doing with it.

Comment: wp_list_categories() does this nicely. I was trying to list terms for custom taxonomies in the sidebar. http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories